# Spring data JPA self join on an entity. How do I specify the depth of recursion?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Boot JPA, I am doing a self join on a table of "Person" with attributes id, name and parent_id.  parent_id is a foreign key referencing Person.id. So, a Person will have zero or one parent. A sample of my domain class is below.

```
@Entity(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_person_id")
    private Person parent;

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc
}
```

This actually works just fine; when I query with CrudRepository.findById() for example, I get a Person object with an embedded Person object (parent), which may have another embedded Person object (grandparent), etc until I get to a Person without a parent.

My question is, how may I retrieve only a Person and their immediate parent without recursing any further (no grandparents, great-grandparents, etc)?

I imagine I could simply avoid the join, and make parent_id a plain @Column, then in the service layer do an additional query to find the parent, but I'm wondering if there is some Jpa magic that could make it easier than that.

Comment: Do you mean you have infinity loop in JSON result?

Comment: Nope, it works just fine -- but I would like to recurse only one level deep.  Just the parent, and no further.

Comment: I understand but how you are returning the object? This is rest api? Or you have just problem with `toString()` in `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Have you tried adding `referencedColumnName` in the join column?

Comment: What happend acctually when you  call parent  ? `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "parent" })` on `parent` field should work if you faced problem in serialization

Comment: @Seldo97 This is web mvc -- the object is being passed to thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this was not as hard as it seemed.  Converting my Person entity to a dto provided me with the opportunity to simply STOP at the parent, and not recurse through the whole tree!